# Solution of the ode

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP $$y'=h(t)y(t)$$ with $y(0)=1$ initial condition and $h(t)=1$ for $ t\geq 0 $ and $0$ elsewhere. Prove that it does not have a solution.

Sollution: Let $y$ be a sollution then i get $y(t)=e^t$, $t \geq 0$ and 1 else. but that $y$ is not differentiable zero. hence no sollution.

But isn't the $$y=1+ \int_{0}^{t}h(s)y(s)ds $$ a solution, or equivalent to the problem? And  now  the function $y(t)=e^t$ $t \geq 0$ and 1 else is a solution to the
$y=1+ \int_{0}^{t}h(s)y(s)ds $ I think im confused . Can someone explain me the difference between the integral form and the ODE??

Comment: This is not an IVP for an ODE, as the equation is not an "ordinary" DE at $t=0$. For that you need that the DE is continuous on some open domain and that the initial value is inside the domain. Thus as the problem does not really exist, questions about solutions can not really be posed.

Comment: In other words, you did nothing wrong, and in some extended sense that is the solution, but one would have to define this extended framework of "piecewise" ODE and what a solution there would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of the differential equation has to be differentiable; this is impossible in this case, as you have shown. But solutions of the integral equation do not need to be differentiable. The integral equation makes perfect sense for continuous functions.

A solution of the differential equation will always be a solution of the integral equation. But if the right hand side of the differential equation is not continuous, it may not be equivalent to the integral equation, as this example shows.

Think of the simpler example $y'=h(t)$. There is not a differentiable function whose derivative is $h$. But $\int_0^xh(t)\,dt$ is well defined and is a continuous (but not differentiable at $x=0$) function.

Comment: A simple addition to this excellent answer: the first statement corresponds (partially) to the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).